# c# insert into mysql multiple variables

Tags: c#, mysql

hello all this seems to be my problem
I have a table in mysql and am making a c# app when trying to insert i get a You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OIL COMPANY)' at line 1 which is my companyVal. it will insert with one value and a default for all others but i add the second value it errors out

```
        string ConnectionString2 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString2"];
        MySqlConnection connection2;
        connection2 = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString2);
        connection2.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO spt_proposal     (lab_Prop_Id,customer_Name) VALUE (" + a + "," + companyVal + ")", connection2);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection2.Close();
```

Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes round your strings and `VALUE` should be `VALUES`:

```
string sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('" + a + "','" + companyVal + "')";
```

Also I'd advise you to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Thank you I will look at parameterized queries

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this to start with:

```
// I split the line
MySqlCommand command =
    new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO spt_proposal lab_Prop_Id,customer_Name) "
        "VALUE (" + a + "," + companyVal + ")", connection2);
```

That opens you up to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), as well as making your code harder to understand by mixing code and data, and causing potential problems for conversions (particularly for dates and times).

Instead, use a **parameterized SQL statement** to give the values to the database.

While you *could* just add quotes, you absolutely **should not** do so. Bad data (whether deliberately malicious or not in variables `a` and `b` could be a serious security risk. **Just don't do it.**

You *also* need to change `VALUE` to `VALUES`, but I'd only do that *after* moving to parameterized SQL. Oh, and use a `using` statement to automatically dispose of the command and the connection, so you don't leak resources if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you I will look at parameterized queries

Comment: @bmorrison1982: You should make that a *top* priority. I would seriously recommend that you don't work on *any* other code while you've still get queries like this.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, is the column customer_Name a string/text column? I don't have much experience with mySQL but with SQL Server strings always have to be surrounded by ticks ('). So something like this might work:

```
INSERT INTO spt_proposal     (lab_Prop_Id,customer_Name) VALUE (" + a + ",'" + companyVal + "')", connection2);
```

However, this is generally considered "bad form" and a slightly better alternative is using String.Format or even (much much) better is parameterized SQL.

Comment: Thank you I will look at parameterized queries

Answer (score 0):

Change your `command` text to be [parameterized](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters):

```
var commandText = "INSERT INTO spt_proposal(lab_Prop_Id,customer_Name)" +
  " VALUES(?lab, ?cust)";

var command = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection2);
command.Parameters.Add("?lab", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = a;
command.Parameters.Add("?cust", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = companyVal;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm making the wild assumption that the field types are varchar(80), lol...